# How to present a 1:n Relationship?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, entity-framework, data-binding

I'm working at a project using EntityFramework 6 and WPF. I used code-first in EF6, the important parts looks like:

```
public class Serie
{
    public virtual Operation CurrentOperation { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Operation
{
    public Operation()
    {
        this.Series = new ObservableCollection<Serie>();
    }

    public virtual ObservableCollection<Serie> Series { get; set; }
}
```

This works all fine. So I have a table relationships like `Series (n) - (1) Operation`, an operation can have zero/1/many series.

Now, I have absolutely no idea how to present this relationship in a `DataGrid / DataTable / Collection`. I would like to have something like: (generated dynamically)

```
Operation 1  Operation 2  Operation 3
-------------------------------------
Series 1.1   Series 2.1   Series 3.1
Series 1.2   Series 2.2   Series 3.2
Series 1.3   Series 2.2   Series 3.2
```

The Operation names should be the table headers, their assoziated series below. Normally I use databinding (WPF style), I tried already things like:

```
using (var _context = new ProdPlanNET.Models.DatabaseContext())
{
    _context.Operations.Load();

    var res = from operation in _context.Operations
              select operation.Name;

    foreach (String Name in res)
    {
        DataColumn c;
        c = new DataColumn();
        c.ColumnName = Name;
        dt.Columns.Add(c);
    }  
}
```

Also a try with CollectionViewSource, but no success. I don't even know what is the best / right presentation object for the `View` (DataGrid, a list). Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try and keep this short as I'm not convinced that this question is on topic for Stack Overflow. However, the answer doesn't need to be long either way. The answer is the same regardless of how many layers of hierarchy you have. In WPF, when we have a parent that can have one or more children, we simply display the children in a collection control.

The same goes for your `DataGrid`... each row (the parent) could have a `ComboBox` or `ListBox` in one of its columns to hold the multiple children items. Now even if you had another level of a collection of `Operation` objects, each with their collection of `Series` objects, each with their own inner `Operation` objects, then you can just move your hierarchy up a level.

Each row of the top level items could have a `DataGrid` in one of its columns to hold the multiple children items. Having said that, I feel that at this level, you'd be better off creating your own custom UI, possibly with collapsible `Expander`s, or other space saving measures.

Comment: Thank you, I guess you changed the way I look at my problem. Wish you a nice weekend.